# Help with adding script codes between <head></head> in success.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, phtml, html

Hope someone can help me with this. It's very easy to do I bet, I'm just not used to magento yet.

I'm adding Google Ads to my magento (1.9).. I need to add this script code:

```
<!-- Event snippet for ads page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

only in "order success" page (which is success.phtml). It has to be in Head. I know that I can't just add the code in success.phtml file. From my research, I have to mess with layout/local.xml file.

Could someone explain to me how to do this? Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You should create `frontend/active_theme/layout/local.xml` in your theme. And should have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     ..........
     ........
     <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="header_module" as="header_module">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script>gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                            'send_to': 'AW-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                            'value': 1.0,
                            'currency': 'USD',
                            'transaction_id': ''
                    });</script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
    .............
    ...............
</layout>
```

This should add the script to head of your success page.